# KDE wallaper spanning/streching

Tags: kde, plasma

Is there any way to stretch or span a wallpaper on kde plasma? I usually span [this](https://hdqwalls.com/download/minimalist-landscape-4k-jt-2560x1440.jpg) wallpaper, and I'm going to burst a vein if I can't span it!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can do this automatically in Plasma 5 yet. Your best bet would be to open GIMP and create 2 images that match the resolution of your monitors.

For example: I have two 1920x1080 monitors so I take a 3840x1080 image and split it in half and set both monitors separately.

[Here](https://github.com/tharrrk/KDE-multiscreen-wallpaper-cutter) is a bash script that will split the image for you.

[Forum Post with other possible solutions](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/multi-screen-wallpaper-as-background-in-kde-plasma-5/18018%22Forum%20post%20with%20more%20info%22)

Comment: Thank you.  The bash script you provided the link to is a perfect work-around.